# Combine variables into numeric vector and find distance between them

Tags: r, vector, dplyr

I have four numeric variables that I would like to combine into two vectors, and then take the distance between those vectors.

```
df = data.frame(V1 = 1:10, 
                V2 = 11:20, 
                V3 = 21:30, 
                V4 = 31:40)
```

I can create the vectors this way:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
mutate(vector1 = mapply(c, V1, V2, SIMPLIFY = F),
       vector2 = mapply(c, V3, V4, SIMPLIFY = F))
```

But I haven't been able to force them to be numeric so I can't calculate the distance between them:

```
 # want to be able to do something like this
 df2 %>% 
 mutate(distance = sqrt(sum((vector1 - vector2) ^ 2)))
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations of:

```
distance_df$vector1 <- lapply(distance_df$vector1, as.numeric)
distance_df$vector1 <- as.numeric(as.character(distance_df$vector1))
```

I must be missing something quite obvious since this doesn't seem that difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

might this be an option?

```
library(tidyverse)
df = data.frame(V1 = 1:10, 
                V2 = 11:20, 
                V3 = 21:30, 
                V4 = 31:40)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(distance = sqrt(sum((c(V1,V2) - c(V3,V4)) ^ 2)))
```

Comment: That's great, and super efficient! Thanks!